# Access or capture assert error from unittest

Tags: python, stderr, python-unittest

Access or capture  assert error from unittest to log in file.

## loggerLogging.py

```
def configure_logging():    
    logging.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    f = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s '
        '%(lineno)-4d '
        '%(message)s '
    )

    sh = logging.StreamHandler()
    sh.setLevel(logging.WARN)
    sh.setFormatter(f)
    logging.root.addHandler(sh)
    

    fh = logging.FileHandler("filename.log")
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh.setFormatter(f)
    logging.root.addHandler(fh)


    fh2 = logging.FileHandler("errorfile.log"))
    fh2.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    fh2.setFormatter(f)
    logging.root.addHandler(fh2)
    return logging
```

## test_file1.py

```
import unittest
class SanityTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        logging.warn("test message")
        assert 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging = loggerLogging.configure_logging()
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SanityTestMethods)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

So, assert error is comming in console/stderr from unittest logging but, I wanted to log it in my log file. Is it possible to do in unittest?

Comment: `unittest` doesn't use logging, no. You'd need to provide your own `TestRunner` implementation. You could use the [`TextTestRunner` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/unittest/runner.py) as a guide.

Comment: Looking at that implementation, I see that subclassing `TestResult` should suffice, then pass that in as the `resultclass` argument to `TextTestRunner`.